# Fluent nhibernate Automaping by property name

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Is there a way to map properties of an entity automatically to column names (without code)

```
Class Person
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string NAME {get;set;}
}
```

What I would like is to map this class to table PERSON(ID,NAME) without doing it explicitly in code or xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your properites have the same name like the columns in the table you can use

```
Fluently.Configure().Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(
                    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyEntityType))
                    ));
```

it will automap all classes in the given assembly.